# C++ STL list crashes with numbers over 1 000 000 000

Tags: c++, list, stl

When I try to resize the list the program crashes... Look at that code, try to enter 1,000,000,000 (10^9)... On my windows 7 x64 doesnt work.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    list<long long> l;

    long long n;
    cin>>n;

    cout<<l.max_size()<<endl;

    //uncomment 1 or 2

    //l.resize(n,l.size()+1); //1st try

    /*for (long long i=0; i<n; i++) //2nd try
        l.push_back(n);*/


    //system("PAUSE"); // uncomment if needed
    return 0;
}
```

The max size is over 4*10^9, but still doesnt work... Im using the newest MinGW (G++)

Comment: What do you think how much memory you are consuming with 10^9 list elements? Even if it were a simple double linked list you have 2 pointers (2 x 8 Bytes) + the value (another 8 Bytes) (all per element) which gives you you about 24GB of memory needed. Also note, that the implementations can even require more than just these 2x8Byte + your datatype size per element.

Comment: `1000000000 * sizeof(long long)` is probably more that the amount of bytes of RAM your computer has available. Try [downloading more RAM](http://www.downloadmoreram.com/).

Comment: Why does it crash? Are you out of memory? The OS doesn't have to [and actually, it doesn't] allow you to have 2^64 bytes for your program, even for 64bits systems

Comment: Does it crash ? Does it throw a `std::runtime_error` ? Could you elaborate on the error you get ?

Comment: @daknøk: Actually, [usually] you can allocate more memory then you have RAM. This is one reason why Virtual Memory is for...

Comment: I dont really know. But long long is 64 bit (I think) so It would be 64*10^9, so its about 8*10^9 bytes, so its 7812500 kilobyes, 976562,5 mb and 122070,3125 gb... Okay... I know what's wrong...

Comment: @daknøk +1 Wow, thanks for the link. I just upgraded to 16 GB with just a bunch of clicks. Many thanks for this link.

Comment: @daknøk great link ^^ ;D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since "available memory" is a slightly fickle concept, `l.max_size()` returns a hard maximum. Your "crash" is very likely an uncaught `std::bad_alloc`, which you'd expect when running out of memory.

Comment: To add to this, whilst a process on a modern operating system may have a very large virtual memory space that does not necessary mean the operating system will facilitate crazy allocation (and in this case it clearly isn't).

Comment: @jstephenson: True, but that's a problem for the C++ implementation. If I make a crazy but legal request, it must deny it. That involves translating any OS craziness to `bad_alloc`,

Comment: @MSalters Indeed, was just intending to add some background.